# Why does CopyTo throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: .net, stream

Why does [CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) cause an exception? The code below it works perfect and is what i thought copyto would do.

```
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var memin = new MemoryStream(v.body))
    using (var comp = new BZip2InputStream(memin))
    {
        //comp.CopyTo(mem); //Non-negative number required (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        var buf = new Byte[1024 * 4];
        int len=0;
        while ((len = comp.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
        {
            mem.Write(buf, 0, len);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Because there's something wrong with the contents of `v.body` or there is a mismatch between what the `BZip2InputStream` expects to see and what it actually sees? The exception is thrown from `SharpZipLib`. Read the code and find out.

Comment: @Jon incorrect, stack trace shows it happens in System.IO.MemoryStream.Write after InternalCopyTo and CopyTo. BZip2InputStream isnt in the stack trace

Comment: Great. So debugging by guess doesn't work. Would you mind posting the stack trace and other relevant information so that we can stop doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in `BZip2InputStream.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)`. It returns -1 rather then 0. I reported [the bug](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/15675)

Also CopyTo checks via != 0 rather then >0 as the code in the question does.